# Are Game Center games required to report achievements to the player as they're earned?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am working on adding achievements to an iOS game, but I have a pretty strong hatred of game center, and I don't want to break the player's immersion by displaying achievement pop-ups all the time.

Does Apple allow game center games to not report achievements to the player as they are earned? In the documentation they have a [list of requirements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW7) but it doesn't seem to include displaying the achievement pop-up when one is earned.

I know there's the option to re-skin the achievement pop-up using a class [like this one](https://github.com/typeoneerror/GKAchievementNotification) but I'd like to not show the pop-ups at all if possible.

Answer (score 1):

GKAchievement has a property 'showsCompletionBanner'. Just set it to NO. The documentation says you should then implement some way to display the achievement to the player but so far as I know that could be long after the achievement is earned -- for example when the player launches the Game Center app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html